# Creating a loop that will send emails

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a loop that will send emails in Excel to a list of emails where between one email address and another has empty cells.

The problem is that every time I come to the .send line , the sub ends and does not continue to looping again to the next E mail address.

I hope I'm clear and that I'm not talking nonsense.
 this is the code I'm trying to run ( the Excel sheet prtscr his atach also)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myMail As CDO.Message
Set myMail = New CDO.Message
Dim Login_EmailAddress, Login_EmailPassword, SMTPServer As String
Dim ServerPort As Integer
Dim To_Email, CC_Email, BCC_Email, Email_Subject, Email_Body, Attachment_Path     As String
Dim CustomerEmail As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
i = x - 1
'Do
'Loop Until CustomerEmail = Range("G1")
line1:

    CustomerEmail = Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(i, 7).Value
    i = i - 1



'********************ACCOUNT DETAILS********************************************************************************
SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
ServerPort = 465
Login_EmailAddress = "*****@gmail.com"
Login_EmailPassword = "#######"

'*********************EMAIL DETAILS******************************************
To_Email = CustomerEmail
CC_Email = ""                   '"deepak.lohia@gmail.com"
BCC_Email = ""                  '"deepak.lohia@gmail.com"
Attachment_Path = ""            '"C:\Users\dpk-pc\Desktop\shortcut\photo.jpg"
Email_Subject = "áãé÷ä àçú ùúééí ùìåù àøáò"
Email_Body = "æä îééì áãé÷ä 2/2/2018"
'****************************************************************************************************

With myMail.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = ServerPort
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Login_EmailAddress
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Login_EmailPassword
    .Update
End With

With myMail
    .From = Login_EmailAddress
    .Subject = Email_Subject
    .To = To_Email
    .CC = CC_Email
    .BCC = BCC_Email
    .TextBody = Email_Subject
    If Attachment_Path <> "" Then .AddAttachment Attachment_Path
    If To_Email = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(1, 7) Then GoTo line2
    If To_Email = "" Then GoTo line1
    .Send
    End With



If To_Email = "" Then GoTo line1
On Error Resume Next

line2:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
Else
line2:
  MsgBox ("Mail has been sent"), vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Excel sheet PrtScr:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about using a For Loop with an If Statement to loop though Column G, and if the cell is not empty take that email address and continue, I've also changed your declaration from Integer to Long and amended a couple of the String declarations as they were incorrect.

I've noticed that in your image the you are using a filter, and the code below will also loop through cells that might not be visible, if you are wanting to send the email to only the filtered list, then the code would need slight amending.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myMail As CDO.Message
Set myMail = New CDO.Message
Dim Login_EmailAddress, Login_EmailPassword As String, SMTPServer As String
Dim ServerPort As Integer
Dim To_Email, CC_Email As String, BCC_Email As String, Email_Subject As String, Email_Body As String, Attachment_Path     As String
Dim CustomerEmail As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

line1:
For i = 2 To x
    If Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
       CustomerEmail = Sheets("birthdaymail").Cells(i, 7).Value

       '********************ACCOUNT DETAILS********************************************************************************
       SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
       ServerPort = 465
       Login_EmailAddress = "*****@gmail.com"
       Login_EmailPassword = "#######"

       '*********************EMAIL DETAILS******************************************
       To_Email = CustomerEmail
       CC_Email = ""                   '"deepak.lohia@gmail.com"
       BCC_Email = ""                  '"deepak.lohia@gmail.com"
       Attachment_Path = ""            '"C:\Users\dpk-pc\Desktop\shortcut\photo.jpg"
       Email_Subject = "áãé÷ä àçú ùúééí ùìåù àøáò"
       Email_Body = "æä îééì áãé÷ä 2/2/2018"
       '****************************************************************************************************

       With myMail.Configuration.Fields
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = ServerPort
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Login_EmailAddress
           .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Login_EmailPassword
           .Update
       End With

       With myMail
           .From = Login_EmailAddress
           .Subject = Email_Subject
           .To = To_Email
           .CC = CC_Email
           .BCC = BCC_Email
           .TextBody = Email_Subject
           If Attachment_Path <> "" Then .AddAttachment Attachment_Path
           .Send
       End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: first all thanks a lot for the answer
Currently the code you wrote sends the email once and does not continue the loop אם the next email addres and send it again.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I believe it should work now, not able to test it though, let me know if you encounter any further issues...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.
It executes the loop once (until it reaches the first e-mail address) and then every time the ".sent" command is run, the macro must be restarted and starts from i = 2

Comment: ermmm... This seems to be an issue with your email provider, I have used a similar thing in Outlook and it worked fine,... I'm a little lost as to what the issue might be. :/